# Javascript force insert string into JS object (JSON) leaflet vectortiles

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using leaflet mapping library

for styling purposes this code works for the data_oh.parcel layer if I hardcode the layer name like this

```
var vectorTileOptions = {
  interactive: true,
  vectorTileLayerStyles: {
    'data_oh.parcel': {
      fillColor: "yellow",
      fill: true,
      color: "red"
   }
  }
};
```

However as I am going to be adding multiple layers I need to add that layer name as a variable so I have something like this

```
var layers={parcels: ["#Parcels","http://localhost:7800/data_oh.parcel/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf",'#ffe4c4','data_oh.parcel'],
            footpring: ["#Footprints","http://localhost:7800/data_oh.footprint/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf",'#8b8878','data_oh.footprint']
};

var idArray = [];
var layerArray = [];
function legend_click(id, layer_api, color_layer,layer_name) {
    $(id).click(function () {
        var layer_add;
        var i = idArray.indexOf(id);
        if (i < 0) {
            layer_add =  L.vectorGrid.protobuf(layer_api, {
                    interactive: true,
                    rendererFactory: L.svg.tile,
                      vectorTileLayerStyles: {
                        layer_name: {
                                fillColor: "yellow",fill: true, color: "red"
                                }
                      }
                })
            layerArray.push(layer_add);
            idArray.push(id);
            }
        else {
            layer_add = layerArray[i];
        };
        if ($(id).prop('checked') == true) {
            layer_add.addTo(map);
            }
        else if ($(id).prop('checked') == false) {
            map.removeLayer(layer_add);
        }
    })
};

for (var key in layers){
    legend_click(layers[key][0],layers[key][1],layers[key][2],layers[key][3])
};
```

In the legend_click function the 4th input is for that layer name but the color is not changing on the map, this means the 4th input is not being recognized correctly in the `vectorTileLayerStyles` portion of the code. Again if I hardcode the values it works but passing through on a variable holding a string it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [computed property names](https://dev.to/miteshkamat27/computed-property-names-es6-3ae3) inside `legend_click`:

```
vectorTileLayerStyles: {
     [`${layer_name}`]: {
                      fillColor: "yellow",fill: true, color: "red"
                  }
               }
```

so if that did not work this should work:

```
vectorTileLayerStyles: Object.fromEntries([[layer_name,{fillColor: "yellow", fill: true, color: "red"}]])
```

Comment: still returns the layer as the default blue...so its not working

Comment: your update works just delete that last } and I'll accept!